# How can draw a real-time marker on map using folium/leaflet Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, leaflet, real-time, folium

I want to move a marker in real time inside a map using Folium and Jupyter notebook. I've tried the following but doesn't work

```
for x in range (len(loc_225)):
    folium.Marker([loc_225.values[x,0]/10000000,loc_225.values[x,1]/10000000], popup='225',icon=folium.Icon(color='red', icon='map-marker')).add_to(m)
    folium.Marker([loc_324.values[x,0]/10000000,loc_324.values[x,1]/10000000], popup='324',icon=folium.Icon(color='blue', icon='map-marker')).add_to(m)
    m
    sleep(2.5)
```

Is it possible with folium?

Also, I've tried with leaflet, but same result.

```
for x in range (len(lat_225)):
    marker_next = lf.Marker(location=[lat_225['message_basicContainer_reference_position_latitude'].values[x]/10000000,lon_225['message_basicContainer_reference_position_longitude'].values[x]/10000000])
    m += marker_next    
    sleep(0.5)
    m
```